# Divergence of an improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

> Let $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a *continuous* and *strictly decreasing* function. If $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=0$, prove that the following integral is divergent :
>   $$\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x)-f(x+1)}{f(x)}dx$$

First, it's not hard to see that $f(0)>0$ and also $f(x)>0$ for each $x$.

I think we have to show that behavior of $\frac{f(x)-f(x+1)}{f(x)}$ is "similar" to $\frac1{x+1}$  or $\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}$ is "similar" to $\frac{x}{x+1}$ for big values of $x$.

But meaning of "similar" is not clear yet !

The most naive and rough approach is to show $\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}<1-k$ for some $0<k<1$ and therefore $f(x)-f(x+1)>kf(x)$.

One step forward, it's good to compare $\frac{f(x+1)}{f(x)}$ and a multiple of $\frac{x}{x+1}$ or equivalently to compare $C (x+1)f(x+1)$ and $xf(x)$. But still I can't extend this idea .

I tried more ways but I couldn't find a proper way to solve the problem.

Any hint is appreciated !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$. For every $m\in \mathbb{N}$, we have

\begin{align}
\int_n^{n+m} \frac{f(x) - f(x+1)}{f(x)}\,dx &= \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \int_{n+k}^{n+k+1} \frac{f(x) - f(x+1)}{f(x)}\,dx\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \int_0^1 \frac{f(n+k+t) - f(n+k+1+t)}{f(n+k+t)}\,dt\\
&= \int_0^1 \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \frac{f(n+k+t)-f(n+k+1+t)}{f(n+k+t)}\,dt.
\end{align}

Since $f$ is positive and decreasing, we have

$$\frac{f(n+k+t) - f(n+k+1+t)}{f(n+k+t)} \geqslant \frac{f(n+k+t)-f(n+k+1+t)}{f(n+t)}$$

for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and all $t\in [0,1]$, hence

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \frac{f(n+k+t)-f(n+k+1+t)}{f(n+k+t)} &\geqslant \sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \frac{f(n+k+t) - f(n+k+1+t)}{f(n+t)}\\
&= \frac{f(n+t) - f(n+m+t)}{f(n+t)}.
\end{align}

Now choose $m$ so large that

$$f(n+m) \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\cdot f(n+1),$$

then we have

$$\int_n^{n+m} \frac{f(x)-f(x+1)}{f(x)}\,dx \geqslant \int_0^1 \frac{f(n+t) - f(n+m+t)}{f(n+t)}\,dt \geqslant \int_0^1 \frac{1}{2}\,dt = \frac{1}{2}.$$

But if the integral were convergent, then for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there would exist an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that

$$\int_n^\infty \frac{f(x)-f(x+1)}{f(x)}\,dx < \varepsilon.$$

By the above, such an $n$ does not exist for $\varepsilon \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$, hence the integral is divergent.

Comment: Yet another wonderful answer. It's a pity you're gone...